# Name of a book with a world being overrun by demonic creatures

Tags: story-identification, demons

I read it in the nineties.

The main character is a man who may not be royal but has been named king as no one can fight the demonic hordes. His girlfriend/wife(?) gives him a scarf with either a sun or some representation of summer on it, and it becomes a magical artifact that helps him defeat the demons in battle when he uses it as a banner. Either through arrogance or some other misfortune, the scarf is lost or destroyed and he can no longer succeed against the demons.

Please help me find out the name/author of this book.

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185842/having-a-hard-time-remembering-an-old-book-trilogy (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 4):

This is a long shot, but could it be the Loremaster series by Mike Jefferies? In the first book, [The Road to Underfall](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Road_to_Underfall.html?id=-tJwBvVXw_kC), The hero, Thane, is given a magic scarf by his mother. The scarf does have a picture of the Sun on it, it's called the "Summer Scarf", and Thane does use it as a banner in war. I think the war is against creatures called Nightbeasts.